# Enter unicode strings to the DB in mvc 5 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unicode, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am writing a website using the mvc 5 asp.net infrastructure, and I am not able to enter unicode values ( Hebrew  for example) to the DB.
I am using nvarchar fields, and I changed the encoding of the page to utf-8.

When I manually insert the strings ( not via the website), it works.

Google told me to insert this:

```
<globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
```

to my Web.config but still i get the same result , ??? instead of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the collation of the DB, even though i have no idea why it works, it did.

I used the following queries:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DB_PATH] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE  [DB_PATH] COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS;
ALTER DATABASE [DB_PATH] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```